# What does right:0 in CSS fixed position mean?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why the `div.class` moves to the right bottom.
I really want to know the meaning of '0' precisely in fixed position.

Why does the border never stretch to the right side if I change (`bottom: 0; right: 0;`) into (`top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`)?

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #73ad21;
}
```

```html
<h2>position: fixed;</h2>
<p>An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled:</p>
<div class="fixed">
  This div element has position: fixed;
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the `div.class` moves to the right bottom.

That's what the `bottom` and `right` CSS properties are for. They position the bottom and right side of the element, counting from the bottom and right side -- in this case from the viewport, since position is `fixed`.

> I really want to know the meaning of '0' precisely in fixed position.

0 is a number of units. It could have been specified as `0px` or `0pt` or with another unit, but since it doesn't matter which unit is used, as it is 0 anyway, it is specified without unit. It represents the distance from the bounding box of the viewport.

> Why does the border never stretch to the right side if I change (`bottom: 0; right: 0;`) into (`top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`)?

Because the `width: 300px` specification stipulates what the width of the element should be, and so the rendering has to give up on `right: 0`, as otherwise the width would be different. However, if you drop the `width` specification, the element will take the whole space of the viewport:

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  _width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<h2>position: fixed;</h2>

<p>An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled:</p>

<div class="fixed">
This div element has position: fixed;
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number represents the distance from the bottom/right. So, going  `bottom: 10px` would place it 10px from the bottom of the window. It's basically a way of positioning it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. but i don't still get it. because if i set the bottom 10,(not 10px) it never makes a distance from bottom.

Comment: This is because css needs units. It doesn't understand 10, because it doesn't know if you mean px, rem, em, vh, vw, etc. You always need to use the units unless its 0, because 0 for all of them is the same.

Comment: You have to add px, vw, %, em, or rem.
Only you can skip above them, when you use 0.

Answer (score 0):

@Gerald when you set the position fixed, the element is stand by fixed position in the screen. You can change the position of element with top, left, right, bottom of css properties. For now if you set bottom:0, right: 0, the element is set in the bottom and right corner of the screen. If you want it set left bottom corner, set left:0, bottom:0, and remove right:0. Also you can set px, em, vw, vh or % for example, left: 10px, there would be 10px space between element and left.
If you want bottom center, set bottom:0, left 50%, transform: translateX(-50%)
Hope it is helpful to you~

Comment: Thank you for your comment! One more question plz. What happenes if i set 0 into 100 or 1000 or 10000 whatever? Nothing happens? Then why nothing happens? I wanna know that.

Comment: if no units are specificed, nothing will happen as the CSS-property won't be read. if units are specificed it would just cause the element to overflow out of the viewport (depending on the unit, of course), as an element with `position: fixed` is out of the document flow already - so if you use e.g. `top: 1000vh`, the element would be 9 full viewports "below" your content. so unless you have enough content to fill up 10 viewports, your element would be inaccessible @wogur016

Comment: I added comment to the Gerald's answer.
Again, you need to add unit, such as px, %, em, rem, vh or vw.
But, if you set 0, you don't need to add unit.